# Logical error rate of topological cluster state under erasure channel

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance, topological-quantum-computing, cluster-states

Assume I use the topological cluster state (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703143) to protect against erasure. Assume also that the only noise or erasure that I have in my system is loss in the measurement (or loss of the measurement result).

What should be the logical error rate at the threshold (loss=24.9%) in this case, assuming open (not periodic) boundary conditions?

I know that it is a stupid case, and that in this case I don't need the topological cluster state, but I need this value to validate my error correction simulation. I expected to find this result in the literature easily, but I cannot find any reference writing this value.